# stop deploying osgi bundle if exception occured

Tags: exception, deployment, apache-camel, osgi, karaf

I have a camel application that is packaged as an osgi bundle. This bundle should be deployed in a karaf container. If an exception occured during preparation of the camel context, is it possible to interrupt the deployment of this bundle?

Comment: How are you doing the actual deployment?

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing the preparation in the start() method of the bundle activator, then you can throw an exception and the bundle will not become active. You cannot "uninstall" it though since the installation is a separate process and by that time already has been completed (without errors).

Comment: Of course you could use the exception to uninstall the bundle.